# Linear regression from data with missing values and taking their time into account while ploting

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a pandas from which I would like to estimate the linear regression on each column. The issue though is that, my time series has missing values (nan). For example I did this

```
   line={}     
   slope={}

   for k,v in df.iteritems():
          xm = np.ma.masked_array(df.index.values,mask=np.isnan(v)).compressed() #i used this to mask the nan values
          x=np.arange(0,len(xm),1)

          ym = np.ma.masked_array(v,mask=np.isnan(v)).compressed()#i used this to mask the nan values
          if len(xm)>1 and len(ym)>1:
              res = stats.theilslopes(ym,x,  0.90)
              line[k]=res[1]+res[0]*x
```

The problem is that number of point I get in line is less than the initial number points. How can ensure that even if less number of point where used for regression due to the nan being ignored, I still have a regression line with the same initial number of points(reading). For example if my v initially consisted of [45,42,47,nan,45,43,45], the line obtained will have only 6 points instead of 7. How can I fix this?

Comment: what is a data point with NaN doing in your data to start with? You seem to be asking for the impossible

Answer (score 1):

Oh, so you want to interpolate for `NaN`, rather than ignore them. If you interpolate, using linear interpolation, you will get the same regression, but with as many points as you have. Try:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True) # This will make your index into a new column in your DataFrame.
df = df.interpolate()
```

This will fill all `NaN` in your df with interpolated values. Then try regression. And why such a complicated approach to regression? Copy paste the output from `df.head()` and tell us which columns you want to regress. It should be possible to compute linear regression in about 2 lines of code.